# Which REST-API URL for copying an attributes from one entity to another?

Tags: rest

Let's assume we've got the following use case:
- There is an Entity Adressbook which contains several attributes/fields
- Adressbook A (the whole content) should be copied to Adressbook B via one single API call ( = B contains same attribute values as A)

Which kind of API URL would be valid due to API naming rules?

- PUT `/adress-books/{idFromA}/copy` with the id of B in the body
- PUT `/adress-books/{idFromA}/to/{idFromB}`
- ...?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755220/what-is-the-restful-way-to-represent-a-resource-clone-operation-in-the-url) might help.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that your linked case is already close to mine. The difference is that I'm not just cloning it but instead copying it from one specific given entity to another specific given entity.